# I having issue in Python I believe with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, openpyxl

SOLUTION:

So the solution I found was so I did manage to get the error worked out

```
text = td.text.strip()
ws.cell(row=ro, column=co, value=text)
```

and that seemed to run without error, now I have some more logic errors I need to figure out, thank you for the help

END OF SOLUTION:

I really don't get what I am doing wrong. I am still very new to python. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
import bs4
import openpyxl
import os
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

domain = input('What is the name of your domain: ')
username = input('What is your Username: ')
password = input('What is your password: ')
r = requests.get('Some Website', auth=HttpNtlmAuth(domain + '\\' + username, password))

desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
os.chdir(desktop)
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = 'Report'

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

ro = 1
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    #print(tr)
    col = 1
    for td in soup.find_all('td'):
        #print(td.text.strip())
        ws.cell(row=ro, column=col, value = td.text.strip())
        col += col
    ro += ro


wb.save('WebsiteInfo.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 110, in get_column_letter
    return _STRING_COL_CACHE[idx]
KeyError: 2854495385411919762116571938898990272765493248
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ae.py", line 35, in <module>
    wb.save('balances.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 408, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 75, in
write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 215, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 355, in write
    self.write_top()
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 99, in write_top
    self.write_dimensions()
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 69, in write_dimensions
    dim = SheetDimension(ref())
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line
389, in calculate_dimension
    get_column_letter(max_col), max_row
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 112, in get_column_letter
    raise ValueError("Invalid column index {0}".format(idx))
ValueError: Invalid column index 2854495385411919762116571938898990272765493248
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 32, in _openpyxl_shutdown
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\1\\openpyxl.we3wcfk_'
```

A sample of what the webpage looks like is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0081)http://Some Internal Site -->
<html class="gr__something"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Internal Site</title>

<!-- This loads the code that makes the table sortable. -->
<script src="./Internal Site_files/sortabletable.js.download"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="./Internal Site_files/sortabletable.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family:    Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font:           Message-Box;
}
code {
    font-size:  1em;
}
</style>
<script language="VBScript">
Function frm2_onsubmit()
    If Len(frm2.FilterType.value) = 0 or Len(frm2.FilterValue.value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a filter type and value!"
        frm2_onsubmit = False
    End If
End Function
</script></head>

<!-- Form Validation -->


<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true"><hr>
<table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="CENTER"><font size="5">Internal Site</font></td></tr></tbody></table>
<hr>

<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <form id="frm"></form>
            <td><b>Division Filter:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
                <select name="Division" id="Division" onchange="frm.action=&#39;InternalSite.asp?Division=&#39;+frm.Division.value;frm.submit();">
                    <option></option>
                        <option>3rd Party</option>
                            <option>Some Division 1</option>
                            <option>Some Division 2</option>
                            <option>Some Division 3</option>
                            <option>Some Division 4</option>
                            <option>Some Division 5</option>
                            <option>Some Division 6</option>
                            <option>Some Division 7</option>
                            <option>Some Division 8</option>
                            <option>Some Division 9</option>
                            <option selected="">Some Division</option>


                </select>
            </td>

        <form method="POST" id="frm2" name="frm2" action="http://Some/Internal/Site/InternalPage.asp?mode=filter"></form>
            <td><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; OR &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
            <td><b>FILTER BY:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
            <td>
                <select name="FilterType" id="FilterType">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="PartRequestNumber">PR #</option>
                    <option value="SiteReplenPR">Clarify PR</option>
                    <option value="CaseNumber">Case #</option>
                    <option value="SubcaseNumber">Subcase #</option>
                    <option value="SupplierPartNumber">Supplier Part #</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="TEXT" name="FilterValue" size="20" maxlength="50"></td>
            <td><input type="SUBMIT" name="FILTER" value="SUBMIT"></td>
            <td><input type="RESET" value="RESET VIEW" onclick="document.location.href=&#39;InternalPage.asp&#39;"></td>

    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<br>

<table class="sort-table" id="table-1" border="1" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td width="80">Division<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="75">Case #<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="75">Netbuild #<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="60">PR #<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="60">CCL PR<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="75">Part #<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="100">Address<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="100">City<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="45">State<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="80">Tech Recvd<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="50">Aging<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="80">Case Closed<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="80">-1 Closed<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="100">Label Initiated<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="80">-2 Shipped<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
        <td width="100">Exception<img src="./Internal Site_files/blank.png" class="sort-arrow"></td>
    </tr>
</thead>

    <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Some Division</td>
                <td>Some 8 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some 10 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some Part Number</td>
                <td>1152 Table Street</td>
                <td>Some City</td>
                <td>FL</td>
                <td>10/2/2019</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>10/7/2019</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Some Division</td>
                <td>Some 8 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some 10 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some Part Number</td>
                <td>123 Bable Drive</td>
                <td>Some City</td>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>10/2/2019</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Some Division</td>
                <td>Some 8 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some 10 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some Part Number</td>
                <td>34568 US Hwy 1</td>
                <td>Some City</td>
                <td>AL</td>
                <td>10/8/2019</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>10/8/2019</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>10/9/2019</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Some Division</td>
                <td>Some 8 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some 10 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some Part Number</td>
                <td>8854 Something Lane</td>
                <td>Some City</td>
                <td>TN</td>
                <td>10/8/2019</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>10/8/2019</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>10/10/2019</td>
                <td>Some Exception</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Some Division</td>
                <td>Some 8 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some 10 digit Number</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some Part Number</td>
                <td>8854 Something Lane</td>
                <td>Some City</td>
                <td>TN</td>
                <td>10/8/2019</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>10/8/2019</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Some Exception</td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p><b>Total = 5</b></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
var st1 = new SortableTable(document.getElementById("table-1"), ["String","Number","String","Number","Number","String","String","String","String","Date","Number","Date","Date","Date","Date","String"]);
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: what is the output of `print(desktop)`?, try using fullpath of `WebsiteInfo.xlsx`

Comment: I edited the original post and added it to the end because it was too much to add to a comment. I hope that was the acceptable thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what's causing it, but you are trying to write data into cells and columns that go beyond the capabilities of excel.

`ValueError: Invalid column index 2854495385411919762116571938898990272765493248`

First thing I would change is: `col += col` and `ro += ro` to be: `col += 1` and `ro += 1` in your code and see if that makes a difference. Regarless if that fixes it or not, I think this is what you want/meant to do anyway.

You're essentially tell it to write the data like:

```
ws.cell(row=1, column=2854495385411919762116571938898990272765493248, value=1)
```

Think about it, you start with `ro = 1` and `col = 1`, and then after each iteration you're increasing your row and column exponentially:

```
r = 1
for x in range(0,20):
    print (r)
    r += r


1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
```

So try:

```
import requests
import bs4
import openpyxl
import os
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

domain = input('What is the name of your domain: ')
username = input('What is your Username: ')
password = input('What is your password: ')
r = requests.get('Some Website', auth=HttpNtlmAuth(domain + '\\' + username, password))

desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
os.chdir(desktop)
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = 'Report'

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

ro = 1
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    #print(tr)
    col = 1
    for td in soup.find_all('td'):
        #print(td.text.strip())
        ws.cell(row=ro, column=col, value = td.text.strip())
        col += 1  # <---- CHANGED HERE
    ro += 1  # <------ CHANGED HERE


wb.save('WebsiteInfo.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Have you considered using Pandas to use `.read_html()` in the html (since you're pulling `<tr>` tags, I'm assuming there are `<table>` tags) and then just use pandas `.to_excel()` function?

Comment: So I did figure out that if I comment out the ws.cell part and uncomment the print it runs fine. Although you were right, that was a major logic error in my for loop =P 

```
ro = 1
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
     co = 1
     for td in soup.find_all('td'):
         print(td.text.strip())
         #ws.cell(row=ro, column=co, value=td.text.strip())
         co += co
     ro += ro
```

So my issue seems to be the ```ws.cell(row=ro, column=co, value=td.text.strip())```

Comment: I have never heard of Panda's, do you think that would be better for what I am doing? It's effectively a sortable table that I would I am basically trying to download into an excel sheet, then fancy it up in the excel sheet with Styles and colors =) 

The top of the page does say the following if that helps
<!-- This loads the code that makes the table sortable. -->
<SCRIPT SRC="/includes/sortabletable/js/sortabletable.js"></SCRIPT>
<link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="/includes/sortabletable/css/sortabletable.css" />
<style type="text/css">

Comment: unfortunately without a url to reproduce your error, it makes it difficult to debug your code.

Comment: if you are new to python, it is worth taking a look at pandas. It's a popular library for data manipulation. and then also does allow you to read/write csv and excel files

Comment: Ok, to the bottom of the question, I added a sample of the webpage HTML